# How to make enemies not spawn on/too close to player. C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, while-loop

I'm making a "player fish eats smaller fish and grows" game as practice. But I'm struggling with making the npc fish not spawn on or too close to the player.
This is the code for the spawner, atm fish can still spawn on the player.

```
    public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] itemsToPickFrom;
    public int numberToSpawn;
    
    float placeX;
    float placeY;

    float minDistance;


    void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
        
        minDistance = 5f;
    }
 
    
  void Spawn()
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < numberToSpawn; i++)
      {
          int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, itemsToPickFrom.Length);
          
          placeX = Random.Range(-10f, 9f);
          placeY = Random.Range(-4f, 4f);

          while (Vector2.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position, new Vector3(placeX, placeY, 0)) < minDistance)
          {
              placeX = Random.Range(-10f, 9f);
              placeY = Random.Range(-4f, 4f);
          } 
             
          Instantiate(itemsToPickFrom[randomIndex], new Vector3(placeX, placeY, 0), quaternion.identity);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Consider adding the "unity3d" tag

Comment: instead of looping until you finally got a position, why not just use the position and set either x or x (or even both) to a farer value? Furthermor you should caluculate the players position once and only once. Nithing to do with your actual problem, though.

Comment: It's Unity or Monogame? In Monogame for second parameter of Distance method use Vector2, no Vector3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's Unity, if so `numberToSpawn` is probably set on the editor interface, so it shouldn't be a problem.

The issue I can see is that you set `minDistance` after `Spawn()`.

```cs
    void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
        
        minDistance = 5f;
    }
```

If you set `minDistance` before `Spawn()`, it could be correct. The other logics seems correct at least.

```
    float minDistance = 5f;


    void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
    }
```

Comment: Btw, for Unity you can also [use objects to indicate the spawn areas](https://forum.unity.com/threads/pick-random-point-inside-box-collider.541585/). So instead of hard-coded magic numbers, you can make the process of tweaking the spawn areas more visual.

Comment: Thank you this solved it! :) And I'll make sure to remember to use the "unity3d" tag in the future.